# Which SCM tools does Jenkins support?

Tags: jenkins, git, jenkins-plugins, scm, subversion

I'm aware that Jenkins supports Git and SVN. What other SCM tools does Jenkins support?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It supports **AccuRev, CVS, Subversion, Git, Mercurial, Perforce, Clearcase** and **RTC**.

For all of them exists a plugin and as you probably already know, Jenkins is not limited to only that list, anyone can create a SCM plugin for other options if they want to.

Here is the link to the plugins:

- AccuRev: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AccuRev+Plugin
- CVS: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CVS+Plugin
- Subversion: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin
- Git: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin
- Mercurial: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mercurial+Plugin
- Perforce: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Perforce+Plugin
- Clearcase: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin
- RTC: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Concert+Plugin

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the list in the previous answer, there is also the plugin that [integrates Serena Dimensions CM with Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dimensions+Plugin). Some more details about this plugin (from the linked page):

> The plugin allows a Jenkins job to be associated with a [Serena Dimensions CM](http://www.serena.com/dimensions-cm) stream or project, automatically updating the Jenkins workspace with file content from the Dimensions CM repository.
>
> The plugin currently supports
>
> - Polling
> - Checkout
> - Build change log reporting
> - Tagging
> - Artifact Upload
> - Tag Deployment
> - Launching Tagged Builds via Dimensions Builder

**Video tutorial**: [Dimensions CM: Jenkins Plugin Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XquDJT90M9I)

Answer (score 4):

Your question doesn't specify which platform (OS) it is about. But if it is about good old mainframes (running zOS, whereas the z stands for "zero downtime ..."), then these would be some possible options to pick from (quotes are from the linked pages):

- [Compuware Source Code Download for Endevor, PDS, and ISPW Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Compuware+Source+Code+Download+for+Endevor%2C+PDS%2C+and+ISPW+Plugin).

  > ... allows Jenkins users to download Endevor, PDS, or ISPW members from the mainframe to the PC. Source can then be accessed on the PC, for example, for SonarQube analysis and reporting.
- [IBM zOS Connector](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/IBM+zOS+Connector).

  > ... provides its functions via FTP connection to IBM z/OS LPAR. You can configure your SCLM project on z/OS and then check for the changes via Jenkins.
  >
  > Features include:
  >
  > - Submission of user JCL job (with optional log collected upon finish).
  > - Introduction of SCLM as SCM for your projects allowing to checkout SCLM changes.
  > - The ability to build SCLM projects currently can be performed only via 'Submit zOS Job' build action.

PS: if you're not familiar with the typical SCM solutions on this platform (such as Endevor or ISPW), then have a look at the [typical SCM solutions exist for managing mainframe software](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/273/which-scm-solutions-exist-for-managing-mainframe-software/275#275).